# I have question regarding set command of Xticklabel in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have the following code:

```
  mean_h =[11.3579,9.8330,13.4154];
   std_h = [11.3427,6.8093,9.4281];
   figure
   hold on
   h = bar(1:3,mean_h);
   errorbar(1:3,mean_h,std_h,'s');
```

Now I am getting 3 bars with error bars on it . I want to label each bar along x axis with separate name: like bar 1 with 4 , bar 2 with 6 and bar 3 with 8.

How can I do that in MATLAB with code?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`XTick`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xticks.html) to define where you want labels, and [`XTickLabel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xticklabels.html) to change the name, so in your case:

```
mean_h =[11.3579,9.8330,13.4154];
std_h = [11.3427,6.8093,9.4281];
figure
hold on
h = bar(1:3,mean_h);
errorbar(1:3,mean_h,std_h,'s');                    
set(gca,'XTick', 1:3);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'4','6','8'});
```

Or for versions R2016b and younger you can also use

```
mean_h =[11.3579,9.8330,13.4154];
std_h = [11.3427,6.8093,9.4281];
figure
hold on
h = bar(1:3,mean_h);
errorbar(1:3,mean_h,std_h,'s');                    
xticks(1:3);
xticklabels({'4','6','8'});
```

Comment: Thanks. I really works . I have one more question. If i want to show the legend of the bar and also error bar how can i do that . Can you help me with code?

Comment: When you know that it's a duplicate, why did you still post the answer?

Comment: I am sorry for again posting. Can you help me with code regarding legends of bar and error bar

Comment: @AhmadBilal you can use [legend](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html?s_tid=doc_ta) for that

Comment: @SardarUsama because the other answer doesn't contain the method for versions R2016b and younger

Comment: Which means that you should post your answer there; not here

Comment: i know about legend but i am confused how to use separately legend for bar as well as error bars. Can u help me with some code